# Undefined is not a function error

Tags: webforms, javascript

I have a jquery code that is supposed to complete certain fields on my webform but am getting an Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function for the following line:

```
 $("#city").autocomplete(ac_config);
```

The following is my entire jquery:

```
   Drupal.behaviors.mywebform = {
attach: function (context, settings) {
    var ac_config = {
        source: "/devtest/sites/democities.php",
        select: function(event, ui){
            $("#city").val(ui.item.city);
            $("#state").val(ui.item.state);
            $("#zip").val(ui.item.zip);
        },
        minLength:1
    };
    $("#city").autocomplete(ac_config);
  }};
```

And the following is my php file:

```
$cities = array(
    array('city'=>'New York', state=>'NY', zip=>'10001'),
    array('city'=>'Los Angeles', state=>'CA', zip=>'90001'),
    array('city'=>'Chicago', state=>'IL', zip=>'60601'),
    array('city'=>'Houston', state=>'TX', zip=>'77001'),
    array('city'=>'Phoenix', state=>'AZ', zip=>'85001'),
    array('city'=>'Philadelphia', state=>'PA', zip=>'19019'),
);
```

// Cleaning up the term
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));

// Rudimentary search
$matches = array();
foreach($cities as $city){
    if(stripos($city['city'], $term) !== false){
        // Add the necessary "value" and "label" fields and append to result set
        $city['value'] = $city['city'];
        $city['label'] = "{$city['city']}, {$city['state']} {$city['zip']}";
        $matches[] = $city;
    }
}

// Truncate, encode and return the results
$matches = array_slice($matches, 0, 5);
print json_encode($matches);

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have this code around your Drupal.behaviors.mywebform?

`(function ($) {

})(jQuery);`

Comment: Negative. Where would that go? I did notice that I did not have the links for the library and I added them to my tpl file. Error goes away in Firebug but still not having the script do anything.

Comment: see https://www.drupal.org/node/171213 - JavaScript closures, the second example.

Comment: Got it to work. My issue was that I had the labels wrong on my php (forgot the edit-submitted-).